# How can I dynamically select a limited number of items using 2 MySQL queries?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

On the homepage of my web application I will be displaying a limited number of items. I have 2 queries from 2 different tables in order to display these particular items:

- 'table1' contains a list of all the items for my application
- 'table2' contains a column which is used as a reference id to certain items with the same id from 'table1'

This allows me to select which items to display on the homepage.

I have 2 queries:

- `$t1_items = DB::fetch("SELECT * FROM 'table1'");`
- `$t2_items = DB::fetch("SELECT * FROM 'table2'");`

I have 2 `foreach` loops that run through each table, and compares the id from 'table2' with each item in the 'table1'. If the ids from both tables match, it displays the item on the homepage.

This allows me to select the items I want to display on the homepage by changing the reference id for each item in 'table2'.

Here's my code for the `foreach` loops:

```
<?php   
    foreach ($t1_items as $i => $t1_item) {
        foreach ($t2_items as $i => $t2_item) {
            if ($t1_item->id == $t2_item->ref_id) {
                echo $t1_item->title;
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Here's the table structure:

table1: `position_name - ref_id`

table2: `id - title`

This code works perfectly fine, the only problem is that it's obviously extremely inefficient since it has to scan through every single item in my database tables in order to grab only a few select items.

Is there a way that I can make `$t1_items` only dynamically query the items which have the same id the same as each reference id from `$t2_items`? I need something that is optimised, fast and lightweight in order to support heavy traffic.

Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: can you post your php code that executes the queries in context? You would need to get the IDs from the first query and concat them into your query string for the second query

Comment: Also please post the table structures.

Comment: can you post both table structure where column matched

Comment: Sure, sorry I didn't know

Answer (score 7):

Have you tried to join the tables into one query?

ie:

```
select 
    t1.* 
from table1 t1 inner join 
     table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.ref_id
```

that will return all rows from `table1` that have a row with `ref_id=id` in `table2`.

Comment: This is a common beginner's mistake to handle heavy db lifting in the app.  The matching of id's should be handled by the database engine.

Comment: I will try that and get back to you. Thanks :)

Comment: I'm new to this, can you please explain why 't1' and 'table1' are separate? Also, what does 't1.*' do?

Comment: I'm not really sure what your exact setup is so i can't really say why it's done like that.  You can read more on Data Normalization, there's even a wikipedia article on it: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: I tried using your code and it wasn't valid syntax. Are you missing ' ' or something?

Comment: I created a sql fiddle for this using mysql 5.6, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7418c/1

Comment: if you want values from both t1 and t2 you can do something like select t1.*, t2.* ...

Comment: Ok, I see. I have another question: If I want to select individual tiles should I have a query for each tile, or should I loop through all of them to display the tile I need? For example I might have the tiles 'main1', 'main2' and 'main3', but I only want to display the title with the ref_id that corresponds to main1.

Comment: Also, how can I access the rows of 'table2'? The query result is stored as an object, but how can I access this object if the query has 2 table results in it? Normally I would just do something like '$item->title', but now that's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a subquery in your first query to only pull in items that exist in table2?

```
$t1_items = DB::fetch("SELECT * FROM 'table1' as t1 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM 'table2' as t2 WHERE t1.id = t2.ref_id)");
```

This way you accomplish everything in a single query and let the database do the work.

Comment: Subqueries are a no-go for heavy traffic. Each subquery generates a temp-table. This will cause major performance impact on the database server. Use joins, so the database can use it's own existing indexes

Comment: Interesting. Coming from my Oracle background subqueries were always the most efficient mechanism and preferred over joins. Perhaps if we put the subquery in the JOIN as Chris London does here (http://www.chrislondon.co/joins-vs-subqueries/) it would be the most efficient.

Comment: In MySQL it always generates an unindexable reference in your where clause. Combining with Joins might work as well. But in this exact case it provides no additional value in my opinion. Also look at the first line in your example. Given the question i hardly think the DB is that optimized so a subselect might be viable

Comment: Interestingly, in Chris London's test, the subquery performed better than the LEFT JOIN. Maybe an INNER JOIN, like the top answer here suggests would be more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

use following code to get all records from table1 which are also in table2 table as foreign key ref_id

```
$items = DB::fetch("SELECT * FROM `table1` t1 LEFT JOIN `table2` t2 ON `t2`.ref_id = `t2`.id");
```

Now, use following loop to loop over all records

```
<?php   
foreach ($items as $i => $item) {
     // Displays the item
}
```

?>

Comment: What's the difference between 'INNER JOIN' and 'LEFT JOIN' in this scenario?

Comment: left join will return all rows from table 1 even if no rows exist in table 2 that reference the row in table 1.